# Use menus with anchors

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, permalinks

I have a CPT archive page and I want to create a navigation menu which will jump to anchors in the form

`<a name="post-slug" http="{the permalink goes here}>The CPT Title</a>`

I have been able to create the anchors in the template file so that's not a problem

For the links themselves at the top of the page I could either create them manually or by using custom links in the WordPress menu system .... but there are a good few so what I would rather try to do is to create a regular menu in the WordPress menu system. The problem with this is that I would need to adjust it's output somehow to change the regular links

`href = "http://example.com/post-slug"`

to something more like

`href = "/#post-slug"`

I am wondering is there any way I can adjust wp_nav_menu() to do this ... or is there any other technique that I could use

NB. For clarity here please note that I am not referring to anchors within the editor or anything to do with the editor, this is entirely to do with template files and the WordPress Menu System and I won't be using the editor at all in this instance.

Comment: Hi. If you can accept your answer then that will help keep the site tidy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it --- needed to use a walker function. I used a slightly modified version of the one in [this tutorial](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output/)

The main thing I modified was changing

`$attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url) .'"' : '';`

to

`$attributes .= ' href="#'   . esc_attr( basename(get_permalink()) ) .'"' ;`

but I will probably refactor the whole thing